# Iframe, scrolling on y

Tags: html, css, iframe

can you tell me why i cant scroll on full width of webiste. 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKPaao?editors=1100 . And what do you think about this solution for iframe in defrent screen sizes? my iframe is loosing right position in defrent sreen sizes, maybe there is some better way to do this.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #D5CC5A; overflow-Y: hidden; overflow-x: scroll;  margin: 15px auto; max-width: 700px;">
```

Your browser does not support iframes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scroll because you have set `scrolling="no"`. Remove that, and remove the `overflow-Y: hidden;` and some weird `margin`s too.

I cleaned up your pen, [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMMPrL?editors=1100)

Comment: thanks for you help. But it is no what i want to gain. Probably i did it wrong way but i just want to see wheatear table and be able to scroll on X on full width. 
Also i put this @ media for various screens because it change position of iframe in different screen resolutions.